# How to position overlay directly above view component?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to position an overlay directly above a component, exactly like this:
[image]

How do I do that? I have been unable to find an example for react-native.

Right now I am doing this:

```
<View>
     <ChatMessageOverlay
         overlayVisible={overlayVisible}
         toggleOverlay={() => toggleOverlay(!overlayVisible)}
     />
     {... rest of message stuff here}
</View>
```

But the overlay (which is a react native elements overlay) is always in the middle of the screen, not relative to the component. Here's the overlay code:

```
const ChatMessageOverlay = (props: Props) => { 
    return (
        <Overlay
            isVisible={props.overlayVisible}
            onBackdropPress={props.toggleOverlay}
            overlayStyle={styles.overlay}
        >
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>This is the chat message overlay</Text>
            </View>
        </Overlay>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    overlay: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 10,
        padding: 10,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        position: 'relative',
        top: 0,
    },
    container: {
    },
    text: {}
});
```

Comment: `position: 'absolute'` is what allows you to place an element on top of its parent

Comment: If I do that with the overlay it seems like the parent is the root view. If I have a view component with a z index to make it on top would that work?

Comment: I did try doing that and it worked but now I have the problem where i can't make it invisible if they tap somewhere else on the screen

Comment: Try looking up 'conditional rendering in react'.  There are many ways to handle this. You might want to look into displaying a modal with a tappable background that hides your component.

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do, the problem is I can't get the modal to display right above the message like in the picture